# SQL Row Counting

Tags: mysql, sql

Before I go on, I don't want to use ANY query which involves selecting all rows and counting the occurrences manually. I'm doing this in PHP by the way.

Basically, I have a bans table. Each new record/row is a new ban. The field titled `user_name` signifies which player was banned. Is there a way to count who has the most bans in this table? I really don't want to select every row and then count it out for each player. The table is pretty big, therefore making the mentioned solution impractical and inefficient.

Comment: What do you mean by counting the occurences manually? You could have aggregates using triggers to increment everytime a player is banned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is done with `COUNT()` aggregates, grouping by `user_name`.

#### Get bans by user from most to least:

```
SELECT
  user_name,
  COUNT(*) as numbans
FROM bans
GROUP BY user_name
/* ordered by number of bans from greatest to least */
ORDER BY numbans DESC
```

#### Get only the most banned user:

```
SELECT
  user_name,
  COUNT(*) as numbans
FROM bans
GROUP BY user_name
ORDER BY numbans DESC
/* adjust LIMIT for how many records you want returned -- 1 gives only the first record */
LIMIT 1
```

In your question, you're very concerned about not wanting to count manually in PHP.  Note that this is just about *never necessary*.  RDBMS systems are designed explicitly for organizing and querying data, and are very good at doing tasks like this efficiently.  Read up on [`GROUP BY` clauses and aggregate functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) in MySQL and master them.  You generally shouldn't need to do it in code.

#### Bonus: Get all users banned 3 or more times

```
SELECT
  user_name,
  COUNT(*) as numbans
FROM bans
GROUP BY user_name
/* HAVING clause limits results of an aggregate like COUNT()  (which you cannot do in the WHERE clause) */
HAVING numbans >= 3
```

Comment: Is there a way to make this case-insensitive?

Comment: @Blake Why is that necessary? Do you have multiple casings of usernames in the bans table, like `SomeUser, someuser`?  If so, replace `user_name` with `UPPER(user_name` in both the `SELECT UPPER(user_name) as user_name` and in `GROUP BY UPPER(user_name)`  This will list and group them all as the fully-upcased version of the `user_name`.

Answer (score 2):

gets the top 10 most banned (leave the `limit` line if you want to see all in order):

```
select user_name, count(user_name) as num_of_bans
from bans
group by user_name
order by num_of_bans desc
limit 10
```

Answer (score 1):

SELECT user_name , COUNT( id ) 
FROM  `table_name` 
GROUP BY  `user_name`